# Error 7399 when the Access file has a password

Tags: sql-server, ms-access, linked-server

I'm trying to create a `linked` server to access an old `MS Access` database (.mdb file) on `SQL Server 2012`, but I always get the error 7399 (authentication denied). So I tested with another mdb file that has no password and, in this case, the linked server worked perfectly. I've already given all permissions to the file's folder.

I tried to deny the inprocess in the ACE.OLEDB driver, but, if I do that, I got a new error

> 7302 (SQL Server could not create a driver instance to this linked
>   server).

I can't see what I'm doing wrong. I've searched about this a lot, and I still didn't find out a solution.

Comment: Changing permissions on the folder don't make SQL Server magically know the password. On the linked server configuration dialog in Management Studio, is there a place on the Security tab to enter a password? What about a Provider string that includes `password=xxxxxx;`?

Comment: I see. I changed the permissions on the folder beacause the Access creates another file to have exclusive access to the file. There's a password field, but it's not working when the file has a pass. I'm trying to create the linked server on the SQL Server dialog, but using the sp_addlinkedserver also does not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was the file. I got a Windows XP virtual machine that has the MS Access 95. So I could open the file to delete the current password and change groups permissions. Now the linked server works.

It seems neither Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0 nor Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0 can deal with MS Access 95 security policy. But I really don't know why.